How is this sentence divided? "目を笑みに"
３０超えると色々あるよな～お疲れ!
意地悪そうに目を笑みに細めた日向が、人差し指で香を指しながら廊下へ出て行った。
The character 日向 makes a joke to his older lady boss that "once you get past 30 all kind of things happen!.
Then I don't understand how the second sentence is divided?
i understand "日向が、人差し指で香を指しながら廊下へ出て行った。" hinata points his index finger at Kaori and leaves for the corridor but what does "意地悪そうに目を笑みに細めた" Mean?
Looking 意地悪そう he...? I don't get how he can "目を笑みに"?


意地悪そうに目を笑みに細めた日向

意{い}地{じ}悪{わる}そうに is adverbial modifier of verb 細{ほそ}めた, and can be translated as "in the way which seems cruel".
目{め}を is direct object of verb 細{ほそ}めた, and is not connected to following 笑{え}み.
細{ほそ}める = "to make narrow​", but there is also expression 目{め}を細{ほそ}める = "(1) to close one's eyes partly; to squint​; (2) to smile with one's whole face; to smile sweetly (at); to look fondly (at)​".
Verb 笑{え}む ("to smile​") exists, but is intransitive (and is not movement verb), so it would not be connected with noun with particle を.
This 笑{え}み is noun "smile​" derived from above verb. 笑{え}みに here is another adverbial modifier of verb 細{ほそ}めた, and can be translated as "with smile​" or "(while) smiling".
My translation for this part of sentence:

意地悪そうに目を笑みに細めた日向
Hinata, who partly closed her eyes with smile in the way which seems cruel


I understand 目を細める but I don't quite get what 笑みに is doing here

@Kawase_K I added my translation of whole clause. 笑みに is translated as "with smile" part here.
